# Passing parameters through URLs

Tags: java, servlets, url-rewriting

I've written a servlet which queries a database for a list of messages, the output is directed to servlet generated html. The user has the option of selecting to view a selected message by clicking a button

```
ResultSet rs = null;
try
{
    startPage(response);
        rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td align=center>"+rs.getString("Heading")+"</td>");
            out.println("");
            out.println("<td align=center>"+rs.getString("Username")+"</td>");
            out.println("");
            out.println("<td align=center>"+rs.getString("DatePosted")+"</td>");
            out.println("");
            out.println("<td align=center><form action=dbShowMessage?action='"+rs.getString("Heading")+"'method=post><input value=VIEW type=submit></form></td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }

    endPage(response);
}
```

The code compiles without any error, but when I invoke it using the web server the HTML page displays without the table containing the results or the buttons, but as soon as I remove the  it displays everything; what am I doing wrong here.

Alternatively I tried it with a URL as follows:

```
out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td align=center><a href=dbShowMessage?title="+rs.getString("Heading")+">"+rs.getString("Heading")+"</a></td>");
out.println("");
out.println("<td align=center>"+rs.getString("Username")+"</td>");
out.println("");
out.println("<td align=center>"+rs.getString("DatePosted")+"</td>");
out.println("");
out.println("</tr>");
```

Again it's the same out come; the links and the table displayed after invocation but as soon as I create the reference same story.

Comment: HTML is supposed to be generated by JSP, not by Servlet.

Comment: are you looking at the HTML produced by this code to see whether it's valid or invalid and to see what content is responsible for something not rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it solves your problem, but you may want to put a space before the `method` attribute, that is, change

```
...Heading")+"'method=post...
```

to

```
...Heading")+"' method=post...
```

Besides this, what characters does your heading actually include? No citation-marks I assume...

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid html...

Use this line:

```
out.println("<td align=center><form action=\"dbShowMessage?action='"+rs.getString("Heading")+"'\" method=\"post\"><input value=\"VIEW\" type=\"submit\"></form></td>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not working for some reason, it prints the first record and stops where it should display the button